# How to add arraylist elemetnts to Treeview as childnodes

Tags: vb.net

I have the list of Employees & their contact numbers in database table. I have to retrieve these employees & their details and add the Employee names as main nodes(parent nodes) & their contact numbers as sub nodes(childnodes for their respective employees). Please help me how to write the code for this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the psuedocode for the process:

```
for each employee
     dim newNode as new treenode(employee.name)

     treeview.nodes.add(newNode)     

     For each contact number
         newNode.nodes.add(contact.number)
     next

next
```

MSDN has an example, where customers are added to a treeview and then their orders are added to them - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.aspx.